# Project Server Get project field value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, project-server

I've been using javascript to access to libraries in a site, but now I want to get the value of a custom field in a project.

I've been looking to do this but I've found nothing, clientcontext does not seem to have any way to access a project's data and I've found ProjectContext, it seems the way to go, but haven't found any example.

Anyone can point me out to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a blog that got the answer, my problem was the same the autor had.

Here's the link: [Sharepoint/Project Server App with javascript and Web Part](http://technicaltrix.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/sharepointproject-server-app-web-part.html)

And here the code I developed in case someone else needs to do the same I needed:

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ps.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var contexto;
var proyectos;  
var arr_proy; 


    function init() {       

        contexto = PS.ProjectContext.get_current()
        console.log(contexto); 

        proyectos = contexto.get_projects();
        console.log(proyectos); 

        contexto.load(proyectos);
        console.log('Carga');
        contexto.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Exito), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Error));

    }

    init(); 

    function Exito() {

        console.log('Exito');

        for(i = 0; i < proyectos.get_count(); i++) 
        {
            console.log(proyectos.get_item(i));
            console.log(proyectos.get_item(i).get_name());          
        }

    }

    function Error() {
        alert('Error'); 
    }

</script>
```